# Discrete Mathematics Lattice Theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics, lattice-orders

Why is $(\Bbb Z,\le)$ not a complete lattice ? Where $\Bbb Z$ is the normal integer group.

Comment: Could you please add the definition of complete lattice. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

For a complete lattice, every subset must have a least element and a greatest element.  See for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_lattice for the definition.

However $\mathbb{Z}$ as a subset of itself doesn't satisfy this requirement with the $\le$ ordering.